# Ways to build different types of Virtual Machine images

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, vagrant, continuous-deployment, packer

Inside a CI/CD environment, I have a tar.gz file that I need to package into a virtual machine image.  I want to take Ubuntu Server installation, install some packages, install my tar.gz file, and output the image into various both EC2/AMI and VMware OVF formats (and possibly others in the future, i.e. docker images).

I've been looking at Packer, Vagrant, and Ansible.  But I'm not certain which of these tools will help me accomplish what I need.

Packer sounds like the right solution, but the documentation isn't very clear on how to start with a VMware OVF/OVA image and build an EC2/AMI image.  Or am I able to start with a Docker image and output an EC2/AMI image??? Based on the docs, it seems like I need to start with AMI and build an AMI.  Or start with ".vmx" (it doesn't actually say anything about OVF/OVA files) and build an OFA/OVF.   But can I start with format A and end up with format B?

Is Vagrant or Ansible better for this??

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've gathered.

I found a nicely documented approach that starts with an Ubuntu ISO image, uses a preseed file for unattended Ubuntu installation, and deploys it out to vSphere as a template:

https://www.thehumblelab.com/automating-ubuntu-18-packer/

In order to deploy it out to vSphere, it requires a plugin from Jetbrains.  It uses vSphere/ESXi to build the template image.  Packer docs also discuss "Building on a Remote vSphere Hypervisor" using remote_* key words in the json file.  But I suppose this accomplishes the same thing.

Then to build the EC2 AMI images, I believe you add another builder to the json.  However, I don't believe you can start from the same ISO image as done in the VMware builder.  Instead, I believe you need to start with a prebuilt AMI image (specified by the source_ami field in the json).

I guess Packer doesn't allow you to start from a single source A and fan out to target formats B, C, etc...  If you want to build an AMI, you need to start with an AMI.  If you want to build VMware images, you need to start from an ISO or .vmx (I suppose this means OVF) and build out an OVF/OVA or template.